# Real-time pipeline for processing data, insert into PSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, apache-kafka

I have files that will be coming in daily that I would like to process as they come in and insert into existing sql tables (using postgres). What is the best way to create an automated pipeline?

I have already written the file processing scripts on python which return the data in format to be appended to the sql tables. What is the best way to make this pipeline real-time. That is, have the pipeline automatically process the file as its sent to me and then have the data added to the sql table. At the moment i am doing this manually by batch but i want to fully automate the process. The key missing step is having the file automatically processed by the scrip. I am reading Apache kafka can help but I'm still a novice here.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you're processing files just to load them into postgres, I think adding Kafka introduces unnecessary complexity. If the system that is writing the files can be persuaded to instead write to Kafka, _then_ it would make more sense. But for file -> DB alone then just keep it simple. IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your input here - what would you do instead? I would still like this to be real-time i.e. whenever a file is sent to me it should be automatically processed. Thanks

Comment: Where's the data coming from? I would focus on trying to make that part realtime; using flat files goes completely against realtime really.
Using Kafka Connect there are hundreds of connectors to pull data in from external systems into Kafka.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.the data is sent in by clients. they are structured files ASC X12 (claims files). i would like to have every file sent in to be automatically processed and added to the database (with a returned message to the sender as to the success of it). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the JDBC sink Connector. It will deliver data from kafka to postgresql in real time. It is possible to achieve idempotent writes with upserts. Auto-creation of tables and limited auto-evolution is also supported. [good connector description](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/index.html) ; [config-options](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#sink-config-options)

In fact, the above connector will subscribe to a kafka topic and send kafka messages to the database table in the stream. You can also subscribe to multiple topics.

minimum configuration example

```json
{
  "name": "name_connector",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "topics": [
    "topic_name"
  ],
  "connection.url": "postgresql://log:pass@hostname:5432/db",
  "dialect.name": "PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect",
  "insert.mode": "INSERT",
  "batch.size": "10",
  "table.types": [
    "table"
  ],
  "auto.create": true
}
```